# Unable to read jsonb columns in Postgres as StructType in Spark

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create a Spark DataFrame by reading a Postgres table. Postgres table has some columns of type **json** and **jsonb**. Instead of parsing these columns as of type **StructType**, Spark is converting it as of type **StringType**. How can this be fixed ?

Comment: You can read this columns as StringType and after apply to_json function

Comment: Yes but that is an addition step to convert/cast the datatype. I was wondering if there is a way to let Spark infer this data as StructType while reading itself from Postgres.